# R Shiny --> FillOpacity Argument in AddCircles Function Ignored

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I am working on a R Shiny project to visualize all of the airports in the world.  The code included below is a sample of my project.  Functionally, the app works as expected - The data table and map update when you choose a different country.  However, I'm having a bit of an issue with the points on the maps.  Since I have the radius of the points dependent on the number of routes from an airport, in densely populated areas where there might be multiple large airports (eg: Chicago), some larger points overlap smaller ones.  I used the FillOpacity argument in the AddCircles function to be more transparent so you could see potentially masked points.  However, it seems that this argument is ignored when I use it in the code below:

```
#Dataset 1: Routes
routes=read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/routes.dat"))
dim(routes)
#67662  9
str(routes)

#Dataset #2: Airports
airports=read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports-extended.dat"))
dim(airports)
#12667 14

#Rename columns
colnames(routes)=c("Airline","AirlineID","IATA","SourceAP_ID","DestinationAirport","DestAP_ID","Codeshare","Stops","Equipment")
colnames(airports)=c("AirportID","Name","City","Country","IATA","ICAO","Latitude","Longitude","Altitude","Timezone","DST","TzDatabaseTz","Type","Source")

#Join datasets on Source Airport
#-------------------------------#
#IATA in airports
#SourceAirport in routes (IATA)

fullair=merge(x=routes,y=airports,by="IATA",all.x=TRUE)

fullair2=subset(fullair,fullair$Type=="airport")

library(dplyr)

#Make a new unique ID by combining IATA and Destination Airport
fullair2$UniqueID=paste0(fullair2$IATA,"_",fullair2$DestinationAirport)

#Create column that assigns number of unique routes to single airport
fullair3=fullair2 %>%
  group_by(IATA) %>%
  mutate(Count=n_distinct(UniqueID)) %>%
  ungroup()
fullair3=as.data.frame(fullair3)



#Get rid of duplicates
fullair3=fullair3[!duplicated(fullair3[c("UniqueID")]),]


library(rowr)
library(sqldf)
library(RSQLite)


#-----------Number of Routes from Destination------------#
SpitOutNum=sqldf("select IATA,count(*)
                 from fullair3
                 group by IATA")
SpitOutNum=as.data.frame(SpitOutNum)
colnames(SpitOutNum)=c("IATA","DestinationCount")
fullair3=merge(x=fullair3,y=SpitOutNum,by="IATA",all.x=TRUE)



#Create the full name
fullair3$NamePart1=paste("(",fullair3$IATA,")",sep ="")
fullair3$FullName=paste(fullair3$Name, fullair3$NamePart1)
fullair3$NamePart1=NULL

fullair3$Name2Part1=paste("(",fullair3$DestinationAirport,")",sep ="")
fullair3$DestFullName=paste(fullair3$DestAirportName, fullair3$Name2Part1)

fullair3$Name2Part1=paste("(",fullair3$DestinationAirport,")",sep ="")
fullair3$DestFullName=paste(fullair3$DestAirportName, fullair3$Name2Part1)


table2=sqldf("select Country, FullName as 'Airport Name', City, count(*) as 'Number of Routes'
             from fullair3
             group by Country, FullName, City
             order by count(*) desc")


#Sort by FullName
fullair3= fullair3[order(fullair3$FullName),]

#-----------------------------------------------------
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(DT)
library(markdown)
library(geosphere)
library(htmltools)


airportchoices=unique(fullair3$FullName)
countrychoices=unique(fullair3$Country)

countrychoices=as.character(countrychoices)
countrychoices=sort(countrychoices)


# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title="Airport Analysis"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Country Maps",
                 tabName = "CountryMaps",
                 icon=icon("flag")
        ))
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "CountryMaps",
          tags$style(type="text/css","#country_airports {height:calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
          fluidRow(column(4),
                   column(8, selectInput(inputId = "countryselect",label="Select a country:",choices=countrychoices)
                   )),
          DTOutput("countrydata"),
          leafletOutput("country_airports")
          
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #----------COUNTRY FILTERING---------#  
  
  CountryData=reactive({
    filteredData=subset(fullair3,Country == input$countryselect)
    return(filteredData)
  })
  
  CountryDataTable=reactive({
    filteredDataTable=subset(table2,Country==input$countryselect)
    filteredDataTable$Country=NULL
    return(filteredDataTable)
  })
  
  
  #-------------------COUNTRY PLOTS-------------------#
  output$countrydata=renderDT({
    
    data_table = CountryDataTable()
    
    
    datatable(data_table,options=list(pageLength=5,
                                      lengthMenu=c(5,10,15,20)
    ),rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$country_airports=renderLeaflet({
    
    data=CountryData()
    
    pal=colorNumeric("Yellow",data$DestinationCount)
    
    
    leaflet(data=data) %>% 
      addTiles(group="CartoDB.Positron")  %>%
      
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron,
                       options = tileOptions(minZoom =0, maxZoom = 13),
                       group = "CartoDB.Positron") %>%
      
      
      addCircles(radius = ~data$DestinationCount*1000, 
                 weight = 1, 
                 color = "black", 
                 fillColor = ~pal(data$DestinationCount),
                 fillOpacity = 0.4,
                 popup = paste0("Airport Name: ", data$Name, "<br>",
                                "City: ", data$City, "<br>",
                                "Destination Count: ",data$DestinationCount,"<br>"
                 ),
                 label = ~as.character(data$IATA),
                 group = "Points") 
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this issue?  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `fillOpacity = 0.4` is too high to get transparency for points near Chicago, for example. I got the transparency in the image below setting `fillOpacity = 0.01`. With a lower value of alpha it takes a higher number of points to make the point completely opaque. And I think that with 0.4 and more than 200 rows for airport ORD, for example, you reach this threshold.

[image]

You could try to solve this plotting only one point per airport (that is, only one row in your dataset).

For example with `fillOpacity = 0.4` and adding this code before `leaflet` function

```
data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(IATA, Latitude, Longitude, DestinationCount, Name, City)
```

I got the map in the image below

[image]

Answering your further question in the comment, it seemed that a possible way was playing with the z-index parameter, but I found that SVGs (like Circles) do not support z-index and the order is based on the order in which the elements were added to the map. So I tried to change the code above in the following way:

```
data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(IATA, Latitude, Longitude, DestinationCount, Name, City) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(DestinationCount))
```

And got this result

[image]

You can try also using `addCircleMarkers` instead of `addCircles`, changing only `radius = ~data$DestinationCount*0.3`. If you zoom in enough, you will see that ORD and MDW are not overlapping.

Comment: Hey this is great!  You've solved my problem!  Thank you!  How would I bring those covered circles to the forefront?  If I mouse over Chicago O Hare and see its respective popup info, I can not see any of the popup info for the circles that it covers (eg: Midway)

Comment: Hi, I edited my post with an answer to your question because I needed to insert code and an image